# jquery ajax returning undefined json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Here is the following code I am using. I am trying to do "callbacks" as I will have multiple different calls using ajax in my script and therefore I wanted one function to handle all of this. This is the most basic version of the function below.

```
function gd(callback){

$.ajax(
   {
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: ad + "?a=vocab&lessonID=" + lessonID + "&offset=" + offset + '&nocache=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
      success: function( response ) {
        callback(response);      
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, exception) {alert('error');}      
   } );  
}   

function test(response){
    alert('hi' + response);
}

gd(test());  // returns undefined
```

How can I make it so that I dont get undefined and get the json object correctly to be able to manipulate it inside of the test() function after calling gd(test())

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the reference of callback function `test` to `gd`.  As per your current implementation, when `()` is used the function is invoked.

So use

```
gd(test);
```

instead of

```
gd(test());
```

When invoking the method as `test()`, you are not passing any value to paramter `response` thus getting `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the parentheses ()

```
gd(test())
```

you are calling the function before starting the ajax call. You should pass the pointer to that function, not its result...

So `gd(test)`